# Custom object mapper not load element from file.properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have make this class for custom date on jackson object mapper:

public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

```
@Value("#{cfgproperties.dateformat}")
private String dateFormats;

public CustomObjectMapper() throws Exception{
    super.configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormats); //is empty
    setDateFormat(dateFormat);
}
```

}

my servlet.xml is:

```
<util:properties id="cfgproperties" location="classpath:cfg.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="objectMapper">
        <bean class="com.controller.CustomObjectMapper" />
      </property>
    </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

this not work because variable @Value("#{cfgproperties.dateformat}") dateFormats is null, 
How can solve? thanks.

Comment: sounds like a classpath issue. Where is your props file located?

Comment: on resource folder, but work when the application start and i call other element of file in other class.

Comment: Do you have a property placeholder configurer bean in the context?

Comment: Do you have a <context:component-scan ...> ?

Comment: yes, this scan all package and make this first of all.